# Simple UPDATE crash MySQL sometimes when I execute it

Tags: mysql

I have a very strange problem on my server. My site is on a dedicated host, and runs very well. But sometimes when I'm running a very simple query like:

```
UPDATE product SET active = 1 WHERE id_product = 99
```

I feel that sometimes, I would even say the first time that day (?!) MySQL literally crashed. Even the MySQL service becomes impossible to restart, and I have to reboot my server. If I re-execute the same query, then it takes 0.001 second.

This problem can arrive on any UPDATE query. I try to repair all these tables, I even delete the database + re-create the problem remains the same.

I do not know what can be the problem? Someone has an idea? :(

Comment: Mysql 5.1.66 on a Debian

Comment: If it is a large table that you are updating, and id_product doesn't have an index it could be taking up a large portion of memory.  You might want to try to run EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of your query.

Comment: Yeah, this could be an OOM issue, or even that some OTHER query is running at that time.  Turn on slow query logging, and consider logging dstat output to a file.  That way, after you restart the box, you can look and see what had been happening before the crash.

Comment: Does id_product has an index? And how many rows does this table contain? Are there multiple rows with "id_product = 99"? Are there triggers on that table?